# Django: Get latest N number of records per group

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Let's say I have the following Django model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to write a query to fetch the latest N number of records per team name.

If N=1, the query is very easy (assuming I'm using postgres because it's the only DB that support `distinct(*fields)`):

```
Team.objects.order_by("name", "-created_at").distinct("name")
```

If N is greater than 1 (let's say 3), then it gets tricky. How can I write this query in Django?

Comment: If I understood you correctly: `Team.objects.filter(name='super_team').count()`

Comment: No, I don't want count. I want the actual N number of latest records.

Comment: Are you concerned with the speed?

Comment: Please, give it a try `Team.objects.all().values('name').annotate(total_n=Count('name')).order_by('total_n')`

Comment: @TarasMykhalchuk I want it to be fast. And your solution didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how you can get duplicate names per team, since you have `unique=True`. But if you plan to remove that to support non-unique names, you can use subqueries like this:

```
top_3_per_team_name = Team.objects.filter(
    name=OuterRef("name")
).order_by("-created_at")[:3]

Team.objects.filter(
    id__in=Subquery(top_3_per_team_name.values("id"))
)
```

Although this can be a bit slow, so make sure you have the indexes setup.

Also to note, ideally this can be solved by using [**`Window`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) functions using [**`DenseRank`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#denserank) but unfortunately the latest django version can't filter on windows:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.expressions import Window
from django.db.models.functions import DenseRank

Team.objects.annotate(
    rank=Window(
        expression=DenseRank(),
        partition_by=[F('name'),],
        order_by=F('created_at').desc()
    ),
).filter(rank__in=range(1,4)) # 4 is N + 1 if N = 3
```

With the above you get:

```
NotSupportedError: Window is disallowed in the filter clause.
```

But there is a plan to support this on Django 4.2 so theoretically the above should work once that is released.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Looking forward to trying out the `Window` expression in 4.2

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you'll be getting your N from a `get` request or something, but as long as you have a number you can try [limiting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) your queryset:

```
Team.objects.order_by("name", "-created_at").distinct("name")[:3] # for N = 3
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately